# What's the proper way to use English grammar for morning greetings?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Please advise me on the correct usage of the words ***sleep*** and ***slept***.

> How was your night?
>
> Did you ***slept*** well?

Is this sentence correct?

Comment: "Did" takes the infinitive _sleep_ rather than the past tense _slept_; the notion of past is embedded in the form of the verb _do_ used (_did_ is past tense). It is conceivable that a person might say "Have you slept well?" but that wording is more likely to occur in a situation where the person being spoken to has just awakened.

Answer (score 3):

*Did* is the past of *do*. *Slept* is the past/past participle of *sleep*. When there are two verbs in a sentence, (in this case, do and sleep), using past tense for both verbs is incorrect.

Since you have started your sentence with a past tense, i.e. *Did*, you have to ask

> How was your night? **Did** you **sleep** well?

Or, if you want to further condense the above sentence,

> Did you sleep well last night?

or

> How was your night? **Slept** well?

In the above, *slept* indicates the past action(verb).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct.

What I suggest to my students is to observe the patterns that arise because *did* can never exist with the *past tense form* (in your example *slept*) of any verb in a sentence.

Look at this pattern for **all verbs** using your verb.

Q: *Did* you **sleep** well?

A1: Yes, I ***slept*** well.

A2: No, I *did*n't **sleep** well.

Notice that the presence of *did* eliminates the need for the *past tense form.*

Notice that only when being *affirmative* (i.e. saying, "yes") and **not** using *did* should you use the *past tense form.*

Notice also, that you could answer affirmatively with *did*, in which case you again would not use the *past tense form.*

A3: I *did* **sleep** well.

English, generally, does not like doubling. If a word has a quality (like being past tense, as *did* is, and signaling the past tense as *did* does) then it accomplishes that task for the whole sentence (generally).

Comment: What if i say do you slept well?

Comment: You can't. As soon as you say "do" you are committed to NOT using the past tense in any way. Always remember that "do" is a verb and "did" is it's past tense form. And consider that verb (do/did) to be a special, "super" verb. Your question here is very astute if this were math, but it's not. The value of the verb "do/did" in an English sentence is NOT equal to the value of other, more pedestrian verbs.